# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults objects are being removed randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I am facing a very weird behavior for  NSUserDefaults, the problem is that [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objects are being removed randomly!

My [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] contains around 65 objects(60 small NSStrings and 3 arrays which the maximum count could be 4  and 2 other arrays with maximum count 30..notice that it has never been the maximum case when facing this problem) , one of these objects is a value checking if the user has already completed the registration phase.
When launching the application, sometimes this NSUserDefaults will contain only 5 objects from those 65 and the others are being removed from the plist without appearing again even if i relaunch the app., which lead the user to the registration phase again!!

i am pretty sure that i am using the save function correctly

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Value" forKey:@"Key"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

i have searched google for similar behavior without finding anything that can help!
Does anyone faced such behavior and what is the solution to fix it?

Thank you for any help

Comment: did you try setObject instead of setValue ?
do you have duplicate keys ? values ?

Comment: Sorry i updated my post..i am using setObject in all my project and not setValue..i tried setValue in some but still without success.

What do you mean by duplicate keys? whenever my values is being updated then i save it again under the same key name!

Comment: when checking the plist in normal behavior , all the fields are saved successfully without any duplicates

Comment: can you print out the contents of nsuserdefaults after every key save ?

Comment: They are all saved successfully because these values are being used inside the application by reading them from NSUserDefault and displayed normally..but when i exit the application and reopen it after some time, all these values are being removed (randomly and not always)..Also, the weird thing is that objects related to the registration phase are not being changed when user open the  app and already did the registration before, so why these values are being removed? i checked that no limitations on saving NSUserDefault as long as user have space..so this error is driving me crazy :S

Comment: are you testing on device? simulator? which ios version? it happens no every device you try ?

Comment: i am testing it on devices and simulator(ios7 for devices and ios6 and 7 for simulator)..and till now i am not facing it on every device..3 devices of 6 has been facing this problem and i retrieved the .plist from these devices.. and the 3 other users never mentioned it(i can't be sure if they are testing it as they are supposed to do:) ) ..i never faced this issue on simulator!

Comment: "[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Value" forKey:@"Key"];" Can you post exact code of this line? (For one of the objects that got disappeared)

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"firstTime"];

Comment: Are your keys always strings? are your objects always strings ?

Comment: @LenaBru yes..both always string

Comment: I am seeing something odd on iOS8 - if I update a setting (on my Settings screen), and then go to another view controller that then looks that setting up, I am finding that the new value of the setting doesn't seem to be immediately available on the new view controller - but a few seconds later it will be. This leads to very unpredictable behaviour. I am guessing because of the work to deal with app extensions, they've changed something fundamental with how NSUserDefaults works, even if you're just using it in the 'traditional' sense. I suspect a bug, but don't see similar reports from others.

Answer (score 4):

I do want to help out here, since I have had exact same strange behavior with one of my projects.

So bear with me, what happened to my project is that: I had a singleton class, which encapsulates several properties, and I had overridden setters and getters for those properties. In a setter method, I get standardUserDefaults instance and set object for key, and synchronize. In a getter method, I return the object of the key. Also I have a login success indicator value to indicate if login is successful. And same as your issue, my objects disappear. After few days of struggle, it turns out that the login indicator got initialized to false when Network became unreachable. And in the indicator false clause, I was setting nil objects to user defaults.

My points are:

- Double check if standardUserDefaults setObject:forKey: function calls are logically correct, make sure the objects are **NOT nil** when call
- Check if you have logic (login, Network change etc) that invalidates the objects.
- Run tests, find the minimal steps to **replicate the issue**. Use Debug session to examine the objects. (Give up believing in Random Disappearing)

Hope this gives a lead.

Comment: Also just want to point out, I used KeyChain to retain logins in the end.

Comment: hi @vladof .. Appreciate your help :) My objects are never nil when setting the object in NSUserDefault (i checked every save in nsuserdefault),i didn't understand the 2nd point but my app is always connected to the same network since my connection is never lost..finally i tried the impossible to try to figure out how to replicate the issue..i do the same thing dozens of times and the one that follow with same steps cause removing the objects, thats why i called it Randomly..i am still stuck without any progress about this issue!

Comment: Sure thing. There are few techniques you can try, first I would write code to log out canonical list of all objects and timing in userDefaults every half seconds or so, save log file in document dir, examine the log after bug occurs. Second why not find a collaborator and explain the code to him, some times I find out where I am wrong when explaining to others. So I know you think setting nil objects is not happening, but I am still on the fence. It's unlikely this is a bug of userDefaults, and 99% of time it is our code problem.  Picking good test cases is really the key to help.